# How get previous day in parameter in SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I have a package in SSIS when I have a start date with a parameter:

[image]

However I have a query then use that parameter, but I need to have de previous day here:

[image]

for exemple if start_date is '2022-03-03' I need to set up @SDATE to '2022-03-02'.
Can anyone help me. Thanks

Comment: Is your question A) How can I start my package specifying the value of `start_date` to be yesterday B) Within my package, how can I use the parameter `start_date` to derive the previous day? C) Something else?

Answer (score 1):

This will give the previous date of the date in question :

```
(DT_WSTR, 10) DATEADD("day",-1,start_date)
```

Comment: Minor points to address. The data type of start_date is String in the screenshot which is incompatible data type for DATEADD. As it's a parameter, you must specify the scope. For me at least, that required a final expression of `LEFT((DT_WSTR, 24) DATEADD("day",-1, (DT_DBDATE) @[$Package::start_date] ), 10)`